# Recommendations for open/source text indexing and search

Tags: search, open-source, full-text-search, indexing, shared-libraries

I just discovered Lucene (Java library) and starting to read up on it.

I'm interesting in taking some works of literature (for example, Philo, Josephus), and indexing them, then doing the following types of analysis (similar to what some Bible software programs do):

1) find word x within 2 or 3 words of word y

2) find "work* of * hand*" - would find "works of your hands", "work of his hand" etc...

3) find literary patterns (also called "motiffs") such as they author uses the phrase "in that day".  (I think this might be the trickiest, might have to find all combinations of 2-7 word phrases then count them and rank them, only showing the top 25 for example).  This might show for example that Josephus like to use one sets of phrases, and Philo another.

Are there any open-source libraries that you would recommend? 
My language preferences would probably be 1) Python, 2) C#, 3) Java. 
Ideally no dependencies on any proprietary database.

Thanks,

Neal

Comment: I'm still open to better or more complete answers.  Marked the one below as answer because it was the only one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lucene is the best one out there in my opinion in terms of popularity, community, activity and tooling. I suggest you look at [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) which is built on top of Lucene. Another open source indexing framework I found is [Egothor](http://egothor.sourceforge.net/) which I am not sure what is the adoption rate.

And [here is a survey](http://www.scribd.com/doc/7497914/Survey-of-Open-Source-Full-Text-Search-Solutions) that might be help you in choosing the right one.

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_text_search#Free_and_open_source_software) you can find more open source and commercial libraries. I have seen few of them supporting bindings for more than 1 programming language. If you have decided to go with Lucene, then you might need [Luke](http://www.getopt.org/luke/) for your debugging purposes.

Comment: Does Lucene do the kind of patterns I asked about? Or I need to ask on there forum?

Comment: Find the kind of queries it supports here: http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_3_2/queryparsersyntax.html#Wildcard Searches I highly recommend you ask specifics in their respective forums